# Correct usage of (n)fold, where n is any integer greater than or equal to one?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

Writing a rhetorical piece for my high school english class, I wanted to emphasize the sheer increase from 10 million to approximately 2 billion.

Conveniently, 10 million is 200 times smaller than 2 billion.  That makes a nice, clean number to work with, even though it really doesn't have any significance on the quesiton I'm asking here.

What I wanted to do is to say something like this:

```
two hundredfold
```

or

```
two hundred-fold
```

Just as

```
twofold
```

means two times as many.  The pattern appears to be placing the number before `fold` like `threefold`, `fourfold`, `fivefold`, etc.

Yet, with something like two hundred, how should I space, hyphenate and spell it correctly?

Just wondering because I'm a little ocd about this and would like to get it right.

Comment: [Wiktionary: -fold](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-fold#Related_terms)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Mike's answer is simply wrong. Firstly because *hundredfold* is not a noun, it's an [adjective/adverb](http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&newwindow=1&q=twofold&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=ByiBTsyLLKGr0QX7q_2mAQ&ved=0CB0QkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=4cbda8eccdfde5e1&biw=1427&bih=920), and secondly because the correct form for two of them is [two hundredfold](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=two%20hundredfold,two%20hundredfolds&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=6&smoothing=3), for which there are over 1700 written instances in that link (and not a single one for the pluralised version).

Note that in principle the *-fold* suffix can be attached to any number term, and it's irrelevant if that term includes spaces, as in *two hundred*. I don't think anyone would ever write *one hundred and forty-fourfold*, but it would be valid.

But it's worth noting that [hundredsfold](http://tweetmeme.com/story/842284429/new-production-method-yields-hundredsfold-more-ubiquitylated-proteins-critical-for-cancer-research) is valid, because although it's imprecise, *hundreds* is a valid number term.

Answer (score 7):

"Two hundredfolds" is not correct, and "hundredfold" is not a noun. From NOAD:

> **-fold** |fəʊld|
>   suffix
>   forming adjectives and adverbs from cardinal numbers:
>   1 in an amount multiplied by: *threefold*.
>   2 consisting of so many parts or facets: *twofold*.

For example, in the film *The Big Lebowski*, the big Lebowski tells The Dude:

> And with Brandt as my witness, tell you this:  Any further harm visited upon Bunny, shall be visited tenfold upon your head.

So words using "hundredfold" follow the same pattern.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and explanation, didn't realize the answer I accepted was incorrect.